# Python Scrapy get article body, extract_first() get None

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to use Scrapy to get article body from news site.

```
import scrapy
import sys 
import json

class ReutersPage(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "reutersPage"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.reuters.com/article/chile-sqm-stocks/lithium-miner-sqm-shares-up-2-7-pct-chile-court-clears-way-for-tianqi-stake-purchase-idUSC0N1OX01C'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        articleBody = response.css('div.StandardArticleBody_body::text').extract_first()
        print('######## Article body ##########')
        print(articleBody)
        yield {
            'body': articleBody
        }
```

I try to get text in div StandardArticleBody_body but always get **None** value.

The output is

```
2018-10-26 14:23:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-10-26 14:23:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-10-26 14:23:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-10-26 14:23:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reuters.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-10-26 14:23:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reuters.com/article/chile-sqm-stocks/lithium-miner-sqm-shares-up-2-7-pct-chile-court-clears-way-for-tianqi-stake-purchase-idUSC0N1OX01C> (referer: None)
######## Parse article ##########
######## Article body ##########
None
2018-10-26 14:23:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.reuters.com/article/chile-sqm-stocks/lithium-miner-sqm-shares-up-2-7-pct-chile-court-clears-way-for-tianqi-stake-purchase-idUSC0N1OX01C>
{'body': None}
2018-10-26 14:23:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any text belonging directly to the `div` you're selecting, but to it's descendants. A space between the selector path and the `::` will get `text` of all descendants, not just the text of the node you've selected.

Try this

```
articleBody = response.css('div.StandardArticleBody_body ::text').extract_first()
```

So that you're getting all the text of the `div`'s descendants.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my answer because I brainfarted and mixed XPATH syntax with CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [27]: response.css('div.StandardArticleBody_body > p::text').extract()
Out[27]: 
['SANTIAGO, Oct 26 (Reuters) - Shares in lithium miner SQM jumped 2.7 percent on          Friday after Chile’s Constitutional Court rejected a lawsuit to block Chinese miner Tianqi Lithium Corp’s $4.1 billion purchase of a stake in the Chilean lithium miner. ',
'SQM’s B-series shares touched 29,400 pesos ($42.55) at the open of Santiago’s Stock Exchange. ']
```